# How to loop a function and store the output values from a loop

Tags: python, iteration

I want to solve a function for different input variables Q2 and Q3 *and* store them. Now my question is how to define the Q2 and Q3 and return the values for each step so that I can later on plot them.

```
Q2 = np.array([20, 25, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 25, 20])
Q3 = np.array([40, 45, 50, 45, 40, 35, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 45, 40])


for i in range(13):
    def function(xyz):
        x, y, z = xyz
        return [x -y -Q2[i], y + z -Q3[i], K[0]*x**2 + K[1]*y**2 - K[2]*z**2]

def jacobian(xyz):
    x, y, z = xyz
    return [[1, -1, 0],
            [0, 1, 1],
            [K[0]*x*2, K[1]*y*2, -K[2]*z*2]]

def iterative_newton(fun, x_init, jacobian):
    max_iter = 300
    epsilon = 1e-8

    x_last = x_init

    for k in range(max_iter):
        # Solve J(xn)*( xn+1 - xn ) = -F(xn):
        J = np.array(jacobian(x_last))
        F = np.array(fun(x_last))

        diff = np.linalg.solve( J, -F )
        x_last = x_last + diff

        # Stop condition:
        if np.linalg.norm(diff) < epsilon:
            print('converged with req. iterations:', k)
            break

    else: # only if the for loop end 'naturally'
         print('not converged')

    return x_last

# Answer to iteration:
x_sol = iterative_newton(function, [10, 10, 10], jacobian)
print(x_sol)
```

As output I want:

```
[[x[0] y[0] z[0]], [x[1] y[1] z[1]], ... , [x[n] y[n] z[n]]
```

so that I can plot these in a graph.

Comment: I'd look into the package lmfit, as well as scipy.optimize. I think there's at least one function that will accept an analytical Jacobian.

Comment: You could create a list and in each iteration append `x_last` to this list. Or ... there are many possible solutions.

Comment: What do you mean by "how to define Q2 and Q3"? What is the problem with the `Q2 = ...; Q3 = ...` you have?

Comment: I mean, how to define it in the function sow that the function starts with Q2[0] .. Q2[1] and so on. It could be that it is defined correct already since when I run the script it gives me the value of the first Q2 and Q3 value.

Comment: You are defining the function `function` over and over again and only the last one has effect. Actually, Q2[12] and Q3[12] are used, but you could think that Q2[0] and Q3[0] are used because they are equal.

Comment: You are using `numpy` so the function already works on multiple values. As pointed out already, the functions create a closure on `i` and *every* function will eventually use the same value for `i` (the last one, after the loop completed). If you want to create functions like this (do you? please confirm), then you need to wrap them into a generator function which will provide the closure.

Comment: I see, that makes sense indeed. Sow currently it defines the function 13 times and continues the code with Q2[12] and Q3[12] inside. What it actually has to do is run the whole script with Q2[0] and Q3[0] - save the outcomes and run the script with Q2[1] and Q3[1] .. and so on. Does this answer/confirms your question, a_guest?